# Reloading a python script using a batch file every hour

Tags: python, batch-file, cmd

Good day to all! From time to time the script turns off. Drops. I solved this problem with the following batch file:

```
@echo off
:start
python script.py %*
goto start
```

Please tell me how to reload the script once an hour?
I have tried given commands:

```
@echo off
:start
python script.py %*
timeout /t 3600
taskkill /im cmd.exe /f ; or python.exe ; or py.exe
goto start
```

Unfortunately it does not come out :(

Comment: If you want to run something on a schedule, then use Windows Task Scheduler. Your current idea is crazy, because it runs the batch file infinitely. Technically however, if you were to force close, _(which should only very rarely be done)_, `cmd.exe`, you would permanently end that batch file anyhow.

Comment: Why is she crazy? I need the script to work 24/7. The script crashes every 2-3 hours, and I have no way to follow it 24 hours a day, 7 days a week. What I have implemented solves the problem.

Comment: Or can use *threading.Timer(3600, function)* to run function in Python every hour.

Comment: or just use linux systemd timers on linux instead of windows

Comment: or `while True: function(); sleep(3600)`

Comment: @AlexeyKuznetsov, to begin with, why are you talking in the third person, about yourself? …and whether somebody is a 'he', 'she' or identifies as 'neither' is irrelevant. To 'reload', you would need to use a Task Scheduler to run something every hour to check if your specific python process was running, grab its unique process identifier, terminate it, then re-initiate it, once that process closure is confirmed as successful. My advice before you do any of that, is to try to change your python code in order to attempt to identify the reason for the crashes.

Comment: Depending on the reason of the crash, a try block (which logs the error of course) should do the trick. Alternately you can launch a new thread (errors in threads don't crash the original thread) with the thing you want to do and have the main thread check in on the child every hour.

Comment: Sorry if I write something wrong, I do not speak English :)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
@echo off

:start
cls

python script.py %*
timeout /t 3600 /nobreak
tasklist | find /i "python.exe" >NUL && taskkill /f /im "python.exe" || taskkill /f /im "py.exe"

goto start
```

The script will check if "python.exe" is running (in this case it will be killed), else the script will kill "py.exe". The /nobreak attribute makes sure that the timeout will continue running even if you press a key and the /t attribute on taskkill kills the process and all of his childs